# Building instructions from an LXF file

Tags: software, instructions, ldd

I've downloaded an LXF file from [rebrickable.com](http://rebrickable.com/). Which software do I need (for Windows and/or Linux) to get the building instructions based on the LXF file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You probably want Lego Digital Designer:

http://ldd.lego.com/

Once you have the .lxf file open, you'll want to select View -> Building Guide Mode from the menu. This should give you step by step building instructions.

Answer (score 5):

Although lxf files must be loaded with LEGO Digital Designer (LDD), it's not always the case that lxf files are loaded correct/completely with LDD. This because the fact that LDD uses a database where the parts are stored, but it doesn't contain all parts and the database changes from time to time. When trying to load older files, you have about 100% guarantee that the lxf file won't load correct. Thats why i'm using LDRAW and MLCAD. There is though a conversion program to convert lxf (LDD) to ldr/mpd (LDraw/MLCAD). However it relies on a xml file for the conversion. If this file is not complete or correct, the conversion will not be correct.